# Firebird Select Field From Table where Field = current_date

Tags: firebird

I have a simply but fror me unsolveable question

I have this request:

Firebird Select Field From Table where Field = current_date

The problem is that this field is a text field an holds date in this format: 25.04.2014

How can i convert it that this questions works if it is the current date.

Comment: If possible, take the time to convert this field to an actual `DATE` field.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select Varchar as Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23846292/select-varchar-as-date)

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT fields FROM table WHERE field=
  substring(100+extract(day from current_date) from 2 for 2)
  || '.' ||
  substring(100+extract(month from current_date) from 2 for 2)
  || '.' ||
  extract(year from current_date)
```

Comment: One more: I would like to delete all found current dates in that field after this select how could i do this?

Comment: `DELETE FROM table WHERE field= ...`