# Select Varchar as Date

Tags: sql, firebird

I want to select a varchar field as a date field

For example a field has this value "30.12.2011 21:15:03"

and when i select this

```
select DATE from TABLE where DATE = '30.12.2011'
```

i get no result.

Comment: see [here][1] dateadd should work for you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113045/how-to-return-the-date-part-only-from-a-sql-server-datetime-datatype

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? Oracle? Date functionality between different SQL variants differ quite a bit.

Comment: Wow. You know, your edit isn't a clarification, it fundamentally changes your question. It has nothing to do with dates or times at all, at least as far as the database is concerned.

Comment: Sorry, i changed it again.

Answer (score 1):

You ask about getting the date part of a timestamp field, but what your question is *actually* about is *filtering* on the date of a timestamp field. There is a much simpler method of accomplishing that: you can use the knowledge that all the possible timestamps on a specific date won't have any timestamps for different dates between them.

```
select DATE
from TABLE
where DATE >= '30.12.2011' and DATE < '31.12.2011'
```

Your edit explains that you haven't got a timestamp field at all. Nevertheless, a similar approach may still work:

```
select DATE
from TABLE
where DATE LIKE '30.12.2011 %'
```

Or the Firebird-specific

```
select DATE
from TABLE
where DATE starting with '30.12.2011 '
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the field is a date field, use the `DATE` introducer combined with `yyyy-mm-dd` (or `TIMESTAMP` with time as well).

So use:

```
select datefield from sometable where datefield = DATE '2011-12-30'
```

Technically you can leave off the introducer, but it is 'correcter' in the light of the SQL standard.

Assuming a `TIMESTAMP` field, you won't get results unless the timestamp is (always) at `00:00:00.0000` (in which case it should have been a `DATE` instead).

For the comparison to work, you need to use either `BETWEEN`, eg:

```
select timestampfield from sometable 
where timestampfield BETWEEN '2011-12-30 00:00:00.0000' AND '2011-12-30 23:59:59.9999'
```

or truncate the timestamp to a date (this may adversely effect performance if the timestamp is indexed, because then the index can no longer be used), eg:

```
select timestampfield from sometable
where CAST(timestampfield AS DATE) = '2011-12-30'
```

If the date is stored in a `VARCHAR` field (which in itself is a bad idea), there are several solutions, first is to handle it as date manipulation:

```
select varcharfield from sometable
where CAST(CAST(varcharfield AS TIMESTAMP) AS DATE) = '2011-12-30'
```

The double cast is required if you have a time-component in `VARCHARFIELD` as well. This assumes dates in the supported format listed below. If you use `BETWEEN` as above, you can use a single cast to timestamp)

The other solution ([as suggested by hvd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23846427/466862)) is to treat it purely as string manipulation, for example:

```
select varcharfield from sometable
where varcharfield STARTING WITH '30.12.2011'
```

This has its own set of problems if you want to select ranges. Bottomline: use a real `TIMESTAMP` field!

Note that Firebird supports multiple formats:

- `yyyy-mm-dd`, eg 2014-05-25 (ISO-8601 format, probably best to use as it reduces confusion)
- `dd.mm.yyyy`, eg 25.05.2014
- `mm/dd/yyyy`, eg 05/25/2014
- `mm-dd-yyyy`, eg 05-25-2014
- `dd mmm yyyy`, eg 25 MAY 2014 (+ variations with a `-`, `.` or `/` as separator)
- `mmm dd yyyy`, eg MAY 25 2014 (+ variations with a `-`, `.` or `/` as separator)

Answer (score 0):

select DATE from TABLE where cast(DATE as date) = '30.12.2011'

Date field is a timestamp

Answer (score -1):

Here is the answere to my question:

```
CAST
(
SUBSTRING
(field FROM 1 FOR 2)
||'.'||
SUBSTRING
(field FROM 4 FOR 2)
||'.'||
SUBSTRING
(field FFROM 7 FOR 4)
AS DATE)
```

This took me 5 hours to find this out, maybe there should be a "-" instead of "." but it works.

Comment: Supported formats are dd.mm.yyyy, mm-dd-yyyy, mm/dd/yyyy or - imho the best - yyyy-mm-dd.