# SQL convert into Data field to compare with current date

Tags: sql, firebird

I have one field in a Firebird DB containing dates like this

```
27.09.2014
```

untill no I compared it to the current date with

```
substring(100+extract(day from current_date) from 2 for 2)
|| '.' ||
substring(100+extract(month from current_date) from 2 for 2)
|| '.' ||
extract(year from current_date)

= date_field_to_compare
```

But now i need to keep out the greater dates and this turns out to be impossible in this case, since its not handling native dates but numbers.

So I actually need to do the opposite, to convert the

```
27.09.2014
```

into A SQL date.

Like

```
SELECT date_field_to_compare FROM db WHERE
date_field_to_compare < CURRENT_DATE
```

But how can I Convert this DB Date field into a SQL understandable date?

Comment: This is very close, but not entirely a duplicate of your earlier question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23846292/select-varchar-as-date

Comment: And it is also nearly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23145974/firebird-select-field-from-table-where-field-current-date

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't store dates in `(VAR)CHAR` fields, store them in a `DATE`. It will solve these types of problems, and make things like selecting, sorting etc a lot easier.

That said Firebird supports a number of date conversions from string, and `dd.MM.yyyy` is one of them:

```
SELECT CAST('27.09.2014' AS DATE) FROM RDB$DATABASE
```

Or:

```
SELECT date_field_to_compare 
FROM db 
WHERE CAST(date_field_to_compare AS DATE) < CURRENT_DATE
```

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23857635/466862

Comment: Its an German ERP system where I cant change the DB, so I write into regular VarChar fields. Thanks for your answere that works. But how could I convert empty or non valid data into a generic date like 01.01.2000?

Comment: @MichaelMüller That isn't easy to do (or at least: the code will be ugly). You might want to consider handling date conversion in your application and not in Firebird.